# Windows CMD: Add suffix to all FOLDERS in a folder

Tags: windows, cmd

Have looked and low, but can't seem to find my answer.

Lots on suffixing FILES but I can't find FOLDERS.

I have figured a PREFIX code:

```
for /D %a in (*) do ren "%a" "FARE_%a"
```

Can anyone suggest a SUFFIX code please?

Essentially, I have folders like this:

```
Service1
Service2
Service3
Service4
```

That I need to look like this:

```
Service1_FARE
Service2_FARE
Service3_FARE
Service4_FARE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just switch the String at the end.

```
for /D %a in (*) do ren "%a" "%a_FARE"
```